# Https get vs post

Tags: android, web-services, rest, security, post

I have been doing a lot of backend as well as front end development using java and restful services. My (company's) app is, lets say similar to an email app.

I am making an Android client and many of the requests will have some or other parameter attached. We have enough security in place but I was wondering, would it just not be better to move all requests to POST instead of using GET? Just because all the parameters would be hidden. The params do not have any personal information, its all IDS and numbers and things of that nature to request information from our database. But if someone would get a hold of that and auth token and other stuff it could potentially loss of personal info from our database.

I wanted to get some expert advice here.
Almost everything I have read so far by doing a simple google search on get vs post suggests POST requests are used for sensitive info such as login and GET is used when information is being requested. But since the info requested itself is personal should I just use POST requests instead of GET requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST and GET are equally readable to people who know how. However, in browsers, GET shows variables in the address bar, so they are readily available and people can tamper with them, like changing ?bookid=34 to ?bookid=35... your web pages need to be able to handle this in general by always rechecking appropriate permissions. So if only this user can see this book, ensure the book belongs to the user as identified by the session userID (which is not passed as an HTTP variable).

From your question, it doesn't seem as though you are using browsers, so there is probably little to be gained by using POST throughout.

The one thing you must must must do is use SSL! This is vital and is the best security for protecting data in transit and GET or POST variables.

Comment: We are using SSL on the sever. I am using google volley on Android to make the requests via HTTPS and also using JWT for authentication.

Comment: well I wouldn't worry abut GET/POST then.  GET can be a bit more helpful for server logs, and POST is better for large data.

Comment: GET parameters are also stored by default in proxy and server logs, so it is advisable to use POST for sensitive data for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt really matter.
At least not for the safety of the data.
A post can be inspected just as easily as a get.
Still posts are saver(kind of) because of the way they are designed and how they are handled by the browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp read this for some more info

Comment: POST is safer but only over https.  You cannot secure a GET but you can secure a POST